# Python - How to get 2 same MD5 strings (6 bytes long)

Tags: python, string, md5

We've been given this code. And it must not be changed.

```
from hashlib import md5

def md_half(s):
    return md5(s.encode("ascii")).digest()[:6]
```

So it's parameter "s" is a string. Only the first characters of that string get encoded with md5. The string can be anything. My question is: 
How can I get 2x exact same hash strings (only the first 6 bytes of the encoded string (hash) have to be the same) 
I know it is possible as I did some research: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem 
I've tried to save the string and the endoded string in a dist and check if it exists but this is a very time consuming process, because it can take up to 1/2^128 tries for it to reach the same encoded string. I've did the search like this:

```
from hashlib import md5
import string
import os
from random import *
def random_word():
    allchar = string.ascii_letters + string.punctuation + string.digits
    word = "".join(choice(allchar) for x in range(randint(6, 6)))
    return word

def md_half(s):
    return md5(s.encode("ascii")).digest()[:6]

md_array={}
num_of_items=0
while(1):
    num_of_items=len(md_array)
    print(num_of_items)
    word=random_word()
    if(word not in md_array):
        crypt_string=md_half(word)
        if(crypt_string not in md_array.values()):
            item={word : crypt_string}
            md_array.update(item)
        else:
            print("Found it!")
            break
    os.system('cls')
```

Basicly it generates a random string. Tests if it exists in the "md_array" and if not makes a md5 encode of that string and tests if it exists in the array. If it doesn't it adds it to the array repeating the process. But like I said it's a very time consuming matter. I'm searching for a way to force the so called "collision of 2 encoded md5 strings" to happen. If there is a faster way i'd be glad if you could help me.

Dislamer: This is for school research purposes and is not to be used in any projects. I've been given a task to try to find the FASTEST solution possible.
Thank you all for reading and I hope we find some answers together.

Comment: Why not just enter two identical strings, that would give you two identical hashes. It's pretty fast too. Logic appears to hold up against your task as well, all be it bending the rules a little.

Comment: Take a closer look... it's not that only the first 6 characters of the input get hashed, it's that only the first 6 bytes of the hash are returned.

Comment: 2 Identical strings are prohibited @Torxed

Comment: And yea i'll make an edit, @glibdud

Comment: Better, thanks. Ok, two comments: You still say "Only the first characters of that string get encoded with md5", which isn't true. The whole string gets hashed, so there's no need to limit your input strings to 6 characters. And since only the first 6 bytes of the hash need to match, you only need at most 1/2^48 inputs to get a collision.

Comment: I would reverse your dict, so that the key are the hashes and the values the words. This will shorten the time required to check if the hash is already found, and you don't have to check if the word was already generated, because in that case it will produce the same hash and you'll detect it.

Comment: Thanks to @JLDiaz I've reversed the key and value, also i've made some alterations to the string generator. I've found a solution in 1/2^32.

Comment: What does "1/2^128" mean? I see 2^(8*6) or 2^48 possible outputs and with the birthday paradox that is reduced to 2^24 or ~16 million computations - unless you are unlucky.

Comment: Given the fact that the string is not limited to 6 characters but can be as @glibdud said anything i've increased it to 64. Now you can get the encoded first 6 bytes equal to some other string that has lower the amount of string characters that than alters the paradox equation